# convert byte array from signed decimal to unsigned hexadecimal in java

Tags: java

My requirement is to sign byte array.

I have `byte[]` as **[77,-22,-35,-118,107]** and I have to convert to unsigned one **[77,234,221,138,107]**
After exploring on internet, I think byte array as below should be constructed.

```
byte[] {0x004d,(byte)0x00ea,(byte)0x00dd,(byte)0x008a,0x006b}
```

Is this the right approach? If yes, how this byte array conversion can be done?
Could you please help?

Comment: Um, what?  If you have a `byte[]`, then there's no conversion necessary -- they're just numbers.  It's only in how you print them or whatever that makes a difference.

Comment: I am sorry, I did not get you!<br/> I was signing [77,-22,-35,-118,107] byte[] and it failed. Now I am told to sign [77,234,221,138,107]. So I think they are completely different.

Comment: What do you mean, "signing"?  There's no such thing as an unsigned byte in Java.  You can do things with bytes to treat them as unsigned, though.

Comment: By signing I mean to generate the signature which is a DER-encoded CMS message as specified in RFC 5652.<br/> For this I am using _italic_ **bold** `code` org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSProcessableByteArray _italic_ **bold** `code`. I have to sign this byte array and there is discrepancy as I have mentioned. Server wants me to sign the byte array [77,234,221,138,107] and not [77,-22,-35,-118,107]

Comment: Those are entirely equivalent byte arrays, as far as Java is concerned.  For bytes, there is no difference.